# Purpose of NgControl in custom component

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-reactive-forms

This code came from an online training. The purpose was to create a component in a reactive angular forms.
There is things that I cannot understand since there is no documentation related.

- What is the purpose of NGControl in the constructor ? It is the form that contain the custom input. How does the DI work and detect we are in this current reactive forms ?
- In this case the writeValue, registerOnChange and registerOnTouched was not overidded, in some example it is overidded, how does it work in our case ?

Custom Input :

Text-input.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.scss']
})
export class TextInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() type = 'text'
  @Input() label = ''

  constructor(@Self() public controlDir: NgControl){
    this.controlDir.valueAccessor = this
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {

  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {

  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {

  }

  get control():FormControl{
    return this.controlDir.control as FormControl
  }
}
```

Text-input.component.html

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type={{type}}
    [formControl]="control"
    placeholder="{{label}}"
    class="form-control"
    [ngClass]="(control.touched) ? control.invalid ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid' : null">
    <label for="floatingInput">{{label}}</label>
    <div *ngIf="control.errors?.['required']" class="invalid-feedback">Please choose an email</div>
    <div *ngIf="control.errors?.['email']" class="invalid-feedback">Invalid email address</div>
</div>
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-3">
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="text-center mb-4">
                <h1 class="mb-3"></h1>
            </div>
              <app-text-input [formControl]="loginForm.controls['email']" [label]="'Email Address'" [email]="'Email Address'"></app-text-input>
              <app-text-input [formControl]="loginForm.controls['password']" [label]="'Password'" [type]="'password'"></app-text-input>
              <div class="d-grid">
                <button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">
                    Sign in
                </button>
              </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AccountService } from '../account.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private router: Router){

  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.accountService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
      {
        next: user => this.router.navigateByUrl('/shop')
      })
  }
}
```